# Latex algorithm environment float.sty not found

Tags: algorithm, latex, environment, pdflatex

I am trying to produce a algorithm in Latex but keep getting the same error: `! LaTeX Error: File 'float.sty' not found.`. Even if i recreate examples in new documents.

The problem occurs when I use the package `algorithm` which should allow me to create a algorithm environment. The log file indicates that LaTeX couldn't find the `float.sty`.

A simple solution would been found by just simply adding `\usepackage{float}` to the preamble. But adding the package leads to an error on the line `\usepackage{algorithm}`.

Here is the example code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\newcommand*\DNA{\textsc{dna}}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Precondition:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Postcondition:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Counting mismatches between two packed \DNA{} strings
    \label{alg:packed-dna-hamming}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require{$x$ and $y$ are packed \DNA{} strings of equal length $n$}
    \Statex
    \Function{Distance}{$x, y$}
      \Let{$z$}{$x \oplus y$} \Comment{$\oplus$: bitwise exclusive-or}
      \Let{$\delta$}{$0$}
      \For{$i \gets 1 \textrm{ to } n$}
        \If{$z_i \neq 0$}
          \Let{$\delta$}{$\delta + 1$}
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\delta$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Check with the package manager of your tex distribution (e.g. texlive, miktek or similar) if the float package is installed.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thanks for the fast reply. Could you give me any instruction to do so? I'm not that experienced with Latex.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, never mind. I found the package manager. When I searched for "float", the following packages come up: 'capt-of', 'caption', 'ccaption', 'chkfloat', 'ctable', 'dblfloatfix', and 'dpfloat'. But when I try to install the package with \usepackage{flaot} the same error occurs.

Comment: the two major distributions both have it as `float` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I resolved the problem. I added the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the help samcarter_is_at_toanswers.xyz provided, I obtained a bit more understanding in how LaTeX operates. The problem was that the MiKTeX 2.9 file for some reason didn't exist anymore (or at least couldn't be located by LaTeX or manually).

So I used this [answered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138697/how-to-reinstall-miktex) on to guide me to reinstall MiKTeX. This resolved the problem. After the reinstall TeXmaker was able to download the `float package` with the `float.sty` which I needed to resolve original error caused by the `algorithm package`.

I've little to no experience with LaTeX/TeXmaker/MiKTeX and I'am not that technical with computers. So please let me know if you have a better answer/explanation/understanding of the problem. I will edit/remove my answer.